# Where to begin when asked to prove something in math

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, soft-question

I want to get better at solving math/physics problems that ask me to prove an equation, formula, theorem, etc. Take the example below from *Advanced Calculus by Frederick Woods*:

"**Prove that if $f(x)$ and $\phi(x)$ are continuous at x=a, then $f(x)$ + $\phi(x)$, $f(x)$ $\cdot$ $\phi(x)$ are continuous at x=a, and that $\frac{f(x)}{\phi(x)}$ is also continuous at x=a unless $\phi(a)$=0.**"

I understand from the definition that a function is continuous if x=a for which f(a) is define if $ \lim_{h \to 0}[f(a+h) - f(a)] = 0$. From my thinking, if two functions are continuous, you can add them, however I am not sure of the logical steps to take in answering these questions.

What I want to know is when asked to prove things in such as this, how does one start? Do you begin with the definition? How do I check to be confident my answer is accurate if there is no solution in the back of the book verify my answer?

I'm not asking for the answer to this particular problem but want to begin to understand how to approach problems when asked to prove something. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Do you begin with the definition?" Some times, yes. The solution to any of these can begin with "Take an arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$", then define a suitable $\delta$, then show that that $\delta$ works. But there is a distinct difference between where a finished proof begnis, and where you begin looking for that proof. This distinction is usually not emphasized nearly enough in textbooks, or even in lectures.

Comment: You might be interested in the ideas of George Polya given in [How To Solve It](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It)